# How I have to attach image to my entities?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my pets project, what I do with spring boot, I have entites author and books, and I want to attach image of author to view to near author name be and his image. But I don't understand how I can attach image to entites. Save it to db or something else? make personal view for each author not option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best options is to add a field to your Author entity: `imageURL`. This field stores the URL of the image like: `/assets/img/authors/author1.png`

Then you can save the images somewhere in your project and reference to the image location. With this, you don't need to save the actual image in the database and you don't have to create a specific view for all authors.